# Confusing sentence, work or works?

Tags: grammar, uncountable-nouns

Please have a look at this sentence:

> "Multiple citations of my work during the short time since their publication indicate its quality."

Here *work* is referring to many publications.

I have a tough time reviewing a statement particularly because of this sentence. Is this sentence grammatically correct? I mean are "their" and "its" used correctly here?

Should it be "... indicate **their** quality"? But that's not right because of *work*?! How about "works"?!

The mix of "their" and "its" is very confusing.

Comment: You could avoid the problem by rewording and rearranging the sentence altogether: _Multiple citations of my papers in just a short time after their publication attest to the quality of my work_. But that doesn't really answer your interesting question.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for the quick solution. I also think that I need to find a proper answer for this question, as probably I will face it again in future!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The area can be categorized as a "collective noun number agreement" problem. Even when we are not shifting our conceptualization of such a noun within a sentence, experts often describe the area as confusing, troublesome, murky, etc.

Be careful with any advice or guideline on the topic that ignores British/US standard differences.

I think, like many grammar questions, there is no correct or incorrect, because there is no ultimate authority recognized. I can confidently call it "nonstandard". But here's someone willing to say "incorrect":

"What you also need to watch out for, in both American and British English, is the mistake of mixing up singular and plural subjects and verbs in the same sentence, paragraph, or piece of writing. The following sentence is grammatically incorrect because the subject and verb in the firstclause (government is) are singular and the subject and verb in the following clause (they have) are plural:

"X The  government is by no means environmentally perfect: they have invested only £37m in renewable energy sources this year."

http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/09/agreement-over-collective-nouns/

Those who are "conservative" on questions such as this will like the fact that it's called "incorrect" under Oxford University Press's domain name.

I find it more sensible to ask if the wording is clear and strong communication, or nonstandard and/or likely to distract a reader. To me: no, and yes. Is there any redeeming value? Well, maybe just that it might be fun or cool if a writer could get away with it!

So, I see it as a problem that can easily be solved with rewording. If someone wanted to claim that it's rational to shift the way we conceptualize the noun as first plural then singular, and that it's a reader's problem if they need to stop and figure out why, I'd say: None are officially authorized to stop you, and I hope none is trying to.

Wikipedia also treats collective nouns, but I think does not comment on this specific issue: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_noun

Answer (score -2):

Since, as you say, "work" refers to many publications, I suggest using "works", "their", and "their". And since "citations" is plural, "indicate" is correct.

Comment: Why did it get down-vote?!

Comment: Because it's wrong? Here, *"work"* is a mass noun. Look at the [Cambridge Learner's Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/learner-english/work_2). The only definition of *work* as a count noun they have is "ART/MUSIC ETC, a painting, book, piece of music, etc:" So if you're a composer, your *works* are played, but if you're a scientist, your *work* is cited. Does this make sense? No, but it's the way English works.

Comment: @PeterShor Thanks! What do you suggest to use instead of work? Please submit an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @Sistan - Don't be in such a hurry to accept an answer. Give it a day or so to see what kind of answers you might get.

Comment: You could say *"publications"* or *"papers"*; here, *"papers"* (as suggested by @J.R.) is probably better to avoid repeating the word *"publication"*.

Comment: @J.R. :D Allright...